# mod_rewrite even existing files and folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Or better said, rewrite everything to `app.php` except the `/public/` path. I've been looking around on SO already but couldn't really find a working solution. Basically what I want is that every url will be routed to app.php/route, even when the folder exists - unless there has been made an exception for it. Currently I'm simply getting 403's for foo and bar, however they should be routed to `app.php/foo` and `app.php/bar`. `/public/` should on the other hand not be rewritten.

Something else that would be cool, but is not that important, is that the url `/app.php/` would be rewritten to `app.php/app.php`.

What do I need to do in my htaccess to achieve this way of rewriting?

---

Directory structure:

```
-| projects
  -| SomeSite
    -| foo
      - .htaccess [deny from all]
    -| bar
      - .htaccess [deny from all]
    -| public
      -| css
      -| js
      -| img
    - app.php
    - .htaccess [mod_rewrite is here]
```

My current rewriting htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(/public|app\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Are there any rewrite rules in the other 2 htaccess files? (in foo and bar)

Comment: Quote docs on REQUEST_FILENAME: _“The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server”_ – I think that might be the problem here, that the server has already looked up the directory foo as existing, but found your “deny from all” htaccess in there – and therefor answers with 403. Could you _take out_ the deny from all temporarily to verify this please?

Comment: @JonLin No, just a `deny from all`.

Comment: @CBroe Then indeed it redirects to index.php. Is it safe to remove the deny from all?

Comment: Depends :-) What would happen if the files in this directories where to be exposed on the web? Anything sensitive in there? As long as your rewriting is in place, anything gets rewritten to your app.php, so there’s no chance of reaching the files in there directly. But now let someone accidentally overwrite your htaccess with the rewriting rules …

Comment: @CBroe Well, there are mostly PHP files in there that won't harm a lot however I may want to add a folder with something that is actually not supposed to get public.

Comment: Stuff that’s not supposed to be publicly available should be placed outside the document root of the web server if possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36471/discussion-between-remidg-and-cbroe)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(public|app\.php)(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This gives me a 500 error. I guess I should've noted that the WebRoot isn't my document root, that directory is actually in `htdocs/projects/WebRoot`, if it's relevant.

Comment: Seems to work just like my rewrite rules (Except that yours is case-insensitive). When I go to `/foo` I still get a 403, so nothing different on that. However, as CBroe suggested, I may just remove the htaccesses from foo and bar if that's safe enough. Just need someone to confirm that. Btw, what about the app.php/app.php thingy? Is that possible?